# Error while creating Google Drive folder into another folder

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I need create `GDrive` folder into another `GDrive` folder.

There's the code:

```
private static String createDriveFolder(String folderName, String mainFolder, Drive service) throws IOException {
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName(folderName);
    fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(mainFolder));
    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

    File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata)
            .setFields("id, parent")
            .execute();
    System.out.println("Folder ID: " + file.getId());
    return file.getId();
}
```

I get this error...

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "fields",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Invalid field selection parent",
    "reason" : "invalidParameter"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid field selection parent"
}
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that from the error message, the reason of the issue is due to the value of `fields`.

#### From:

```
.setFields("id, parent")
```

#### To:

```
.setFields("id, parents")
```

#### Note:

- Please modify `parent` to `parents`. At Google Drive, in the current stage, a file and folder have the multiple parents. So `parents` is used. But we can see the following announce. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/simplifying-google-drives-folder-structure-and-sharing-models)

  > Beginning Sept. 30, 2020, it will no longer be possible to place an item in multiple folders; every item will have exactly one location. In the new model, shortcuts can be used to organize content in multiple hierarchies. This simplification of Drive's folder structure and sharing models will result in a change in the way some Google Drive API endpoints behave.

  - I'm not sure whether `parents` will be changed to `parent`. So about this, I would like to confirm the change of the Drive API after Sept. 30, 2020.

#### Reference:

- [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

Comment: @Daniele Romanella Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.